# Why is the edit button is disabled for me on Web Application Meta?

Tags: support, editing

I was looking on this site and then I noticed edit button is not enabled for any question or answer. I can share, flag but can not edit any question or answer. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need full editing privileges - 2,000 reputation - on the main site to be able to edit on meta.